# UIContainerView (Container View from palette) load content on demand

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uicontainerview

I use UIContainerView (CV) in the storyboard, but I need content that this CV only in a particular case. In Connections inspector, I can see Triggered Segues part:

"viewDidLoad -> embed MyViewController"

My question is, can I change viewDidLoad to something else or this is not possible and only option is to make custom container views?